# Using secret key to make a secure connection between Swift app and MySQL database?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

Essentially I need to make a secure connection between my mySQL database and my Swift app. Ideally, I need to make the table data present in a swift table view.

While I've already established a connection between my mySQL database and Swift app using a PHP script, I cannot just have this information show on my website when going to the right address (www.example.com/service.php)

It is important that the PHP script only loads for my mobile app and not for anything or anyone else.

This is currently the code I am using in my Swift App and PHP script to access the database.

What are some changes I can make to my code? Any suggestions are welcome, I really appreciate it.

**Swift App:**

**FirstViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FeedModelProtocol  {
    var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
    var selectedStock : StockModel = StockModel()
    @IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //set delegates and initialize FeedModel

        self.listTableView.delegate = self
        self.listTableView.dataSource = self

        let feedModel = FeedModel()
        feedModel.delegate = self
        feedModel.downloadItems()

    }

    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

        feedItems = items
        self.listTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of feed items
        return feedItems.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Retrieve cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "stockCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        // Get the stock to be shown
        let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
        // Configure our cell title made up of name and price
        let titleStr: String = item.manufacturer! + ": " + item.model!
        print(titleStr)
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.textLabel!.text = titleStr

        return myCell
    }

}
```

**FeedModel.swift:**

```
import Foundation

protocol FeedModelProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class FeedModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {



    weak var delegate: FeedModelProtocol!

    let urlPath = "https://www.example.com/service.php" 

    func downloadItems() {

        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }else {
                print("stocks downloaded")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
}

    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

        var jsonResult = NSArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let stocks = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
        {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let stock = StockModel()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let name = jsonElement["manufacturer"] as? String,
                let price = jsonElement["model"] as? String

            {
                print(name)
                print(price)
                stock.manufacturer = name
                stock.model = price


            }

            stocks.add(stock)

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: stocks)

        })
    }
}
```

**StockModel:**

```
import UIKit

class StockModel: NSObject {

    //properties of a stock

    var manufacturer: String?
    var model: String?



    //empty constructor

    override init()
    {

    }

    //construct with @name and @price parameters

    init(manufacturer: String, model: String) {

        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model


    }


    //prints a stock's name and price

    override var description: String {
        return "Name: \(String(describing: manufacturer)), Address: \(String(describing: model))"

    }

}
```

**PHP Script:**

```
<?php


// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbName");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Equipment'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Test_Equipment";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // Create temporary connection
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Look through each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: None of the Swift code is relevant to your question. Your question is strictly about your PHP file. I can't imagine you are the first person that has needed to hide a username and password in a PHP file for connecting to a database. Searching should give you plenty of relevant answers.

Comment: You'll many other related questions and answers from [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+hide+database+password).

Comment: @rmaddy I think you are misunderstanding my question. When loaded, the service.php file shows all of the data that will be passed to the app. All the table data can be easily seen, this is such a security risk because literally anyone can go on the website and type example.com/service.php and see all the info my app will use. I need to hide that info, not the username and password

Comment: OK, but this still has nothing to do with Swift. This is 100% a PHP question. Please do some searching on how to prevent anyone from running your PHP file and seeing the data other than your designated client (which may happen to be an iOS app but it doesn't matter since your PHP could serve any client you happen to write regardless of OS or language).

Comment: Can you recommend any stack posts or articles relating to this, before posting I have tried to do research without any luck